# Web-to-lead issue with phone number validation rule

Tags: web2lead

I'm running into an issue with a validation rule. I'm not a developer, but I'm determined to figure this out. Here's what I know so far.

A web-to-lead form is getting an error when posting a lead due to a validation rule for the phone number that is **NOT( REGEX( Phone , "^[0-9]*")**. I only enter numbers in the form and still get an error due to this rule. The phone line in the code of this form is **<label for="phone">Phone</label><input  id="phone" maxlength="40" name="phone" size="20" type="text" />**
 I've tried changing the type to phone, phonenumber, and tel which all get the same error.

I found another rule on the web that suggested using **NOT( OR( ISBLANK(Phone), REGEX( Phone,"(\D?[0-9]{3}\D?)[\s][0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}")))** and this worked, but then broke the production environment with the same error - "Only numbers are allowed in phone number."

With both of the Regex codes, I've entered both 1115554444 and 111-555-4444.

Has anybody run into a similar issue?

Comment: It'd be helpful to see some examples of the data being entered in this form field of yours. The first validation rule, for example, would complain about `(555) 555-5555` because it only allows _numbers_ (i.e. digits 0-9, which the `(`, `)`, `-`, and blank space are not). You should [edit] your question to include that information.

Comment: And it looks like you got similar feedback over on the [same question you posed to SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72756217/salesforce-web-to-lead-issue-with-posting-phone-number).

Comment: With both of the Regex codes, I've entered both 1115554444 and 111-555-4444.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the validation rule below:

OR(
OR(
LEN( Phone ) <= 9 ,
LEN( Phone ) = 11,
LEN( Phone ) = 12,
LEN( Phone ) >= 14
),
NOT(
OR(
REGEX(Phone, "[0-9 ]+"),
REGEX(Phone, "\+[0-9 ]+")
)
)
)

Comment: I got a syntax error here; "\+[0-9